# How to test browserify project using karma/jasmine

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, browserify, karma-jasmine

I'm totally new to the concept of testing, and i need one solid example on how to do it in my project:

I have a gulp file goes like this (Not all of it, just the important portions)

```
gulp.task('bundle', function() {
    gulp.src('public/angular-app/main.js')
        .pipe(browserify({
            debug: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/min-js'));           
});
```

This is a slight portion of my main.js:

```
'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp', [
        'ui.router',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'ngSanitize',
        'ngFx',
        ...
    ], ['$interpolateProvider',
        function($interpolateProvider) {
            $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{{');
            $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}}');
        }
    ])

    .config(require('./config/routes'))

        .config(require('./config/authInterceptor'))
        .run(require('./config/runPhase'))
        .run(require('./config/xeditable'))



        .controller('homeController', require('./controllers/homeController'))
        .controller('modalInstanceCtrl', require('./controllers/modalInstanceCtrl'))
        .controller('modalparticipantCtrl',require('./controllers/modalParticipantCtrl'))
        .controller('generatorController',require('./controllers/generatorController'))
        .controller('navController', require('./controllers/navController'))
        .controller('signInController', require('./controllers/signInController'))
        .controller('pricingController', require('./controllers/pricingController'))
        .controller('howItWorksController',require('./controllers/howItWorks'))
        ...
```

Now this is my config file for karma:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'public/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      'public/vendor/angular/angular.js',
      'public/vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'public/angular-app/**/*.js',
      'test/**/*Spec.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],
```

When i run karma with karma start this is what i get:

Uncaught reference error:require is not defined
at root/public/angular-app/main.js

So my question is simple, how can i do tests, for example, on my homeController...

//update

So I updated my test file to this:

```
describe("An Angularjs test suite",function(){
    var target, rootScope;
    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope) {
      rootScope = $rootScope;

      // Mock everything here
      spyOn(rootScope, "$on")
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function(homeController) {
      target = homeController;
    }));

    it('should have called rootScope.$on', function(){
      expect(rootScope.$on).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

});
```

and my config file to this:

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'public/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
  'public/vendor/angular/angular.js',
  'public/vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'public/min-js/main.js',
  'test/**/*Spec.js'
],


// list of files to exclude
exclude: [
],


browserify: {
        watch: true,
        debug: true
},

preprocessors: {
    'test/*': ['browserify']
},
```

Still nothing works, first he says 'unknown provider homeControllerProvider',
Now if i delete them lines:

```
beforeEach(inject(function(homeController) {
          target = homeController;
        }));
```

it still gives me error, expected spy $on to be called, How do i fix this?

Answer (score 4):

You need to inform Karma to run Browserify before running tests.

You can add this in your Karma config:

```
    {
        browserify: {
            watch: true,
            debug: true
        },
        preprocessors: {
            'test/*': ['browserify']
        }
    }
```

Karma config file reference: http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/configuration-file.html

Or have a look at one of of my projects that uses Karma for testing: [smild](https://github.com/mtfranchetto/smild).

Comment: I jest need a simple example of how to inject the homecontroller module when my all program is browserfied based on the content i wrote up there...gulp is taking this main.js and minifies it to another main.js,now if i include that minified into my test config file, how can i tell him :look, inject homecontroller, do some stuff with it...

Comment: You need the angular.mock module from AngularJS team. Here is a question that can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022320/angularjs-inject-service-mock-inside-service-tests.