# Unit testing universal/isomorphic node package file

Tags: javascript, node.js, karma-runner, universal, isomorphic-javascript

I'm trying to create an [universal javascript](https://medium.com/@mjackson/universal-javascript-4761051b7ae9#.olcyaodz3) (formaly known as isomorphic javascript) package. Meaning that it should work as a node module but also run smoothly in a browser

Assume it looks like this:

```
// awesome.js
module.exports = function () {
    return 10;
}
```

Installation:

```
$> npm install awesome
```

and include it:

```
// index.js
var awesome = require('awesome')
```

To use this in a browser you have to use `browserify`

```
$> ./node_modules/.bin/browserify index.js -o bundle.js",
```

No problems so far. However, when it comes to unit testing using Karma and Jasmine I get a `module` not being defined (this is the `module` variable from `awesome.js`)

The karma config looks like:

```
gulp.task('test', function () {
    var Server = require('karma').Server;
    new Server({
         autoWatch: true,
         browsers: [
            'Chrome'
         ],
         coverageReporter: {
             type: 'lcov',
             dir: 'coverage/'
         },
         frameworks: [ 'browserify', 'jasmine'],
         files: [
             'awesome.js',
             'tests/spec-helpers.js',
             'tests/awesome.spec.js'
         ],
         junitReporter: {
              outputFile: 'target/junit.xml'
         },
         preprocessors: {
             'awesome.js': 'coverage',
             'tests/awesome.spec.js': ['browserify']
         },
         browserify: {
             debug: true,
             transform: [ 'brfs' ]
         },
         reporters: [
             'junit',
             'coverage'
         ],
         singleRun: false,
     }).start();
});
```

awesome-spec.js

```
var awesome = require('awesome');

describe('Awesome', function () {
    it('should return 10', function () {
         expect(awesome()).toBe(10);
    });
});
```

For some reason `browserify` doesn't seem to work properly. Any suggestion why this is?

Also, any improvements regarding `universal javascript` are welcome too!

Comment: See [How to test browserify project using karma/jasmine](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26528129/3853934).

Comment: I've checked that post out, but I don't see anything that might help with my issue. Did I miss something there ?

Comment: Did you add `watch: true` to `browserify: {}`?

Comment: That was indeed one difference which I did try :) But that didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done. Karma will not be able to understand node js (server side) code.  Since karma runs on the browser.

Comment: Why can't you bundle it?

Comment: @destoryer how are you expecting browsers to understand node js

Comment: If all we're talking about is mitigating `require`s, you could use a javascript bundler (which the op is asking about), or even a transpiler like babel for browers that understand modules. I don't see what a testing library could use that's not supported by browsers as well.

Comment: what if the source code uses some node specific modules like fs? do you think karma still able to test those code?

Comment: Which source code? There's no reason for a testing library to depend on node environment.

Comment: I mean the source code you want to test. btw, karma is not a testing library. It is a test runner, which uses browser to run test files against source code