# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at node_modules/karma-chrome-launcher/test/jsflags.spec.js:3

Tags: typescript, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

When I run `karma start` I'm getting the following error:

> Chrome 68.0.3440 (Windows 10.0.0) ERROR
>     Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
>     at node_modules/karma-chrome-launcher/test/jsflags.spec.js:3

I have the following karma config file:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({
  basePath: '',
  files: ['**/*spec.js'],
  frameworks: ['jasmine'],
  plugins: [
    require('karma-jasmine'),
    require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
    require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
    require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter')
  ],
  client: {
    clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
  },
  coverageIstanbulReporter: {
    dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
    reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
    fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
  },
  reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
  port: 9876,
  colors: true,
  logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
  autoWatch: true,
  browsers: ['Chrome'],
  singleRun: false
});
```

};

Any one have an idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38573690/uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined-on-karma-start-karma-conf-js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined on karma start karma.conf.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38573690/uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined-on-karma-start-karma-conf-js)